# What complex index of refraction values are used in metallic input in the Principled BSDF

Tags: materials

The Blender documentation states that the metallic input in the principled BSDF when set to 1.0 uses a Fresnel equation, (or approximation), with a complex index of refraction for a metallic surface. What are the values of the complex index of refraction being used and can they be changed? Also,, what is the "Fresnel" equation being used?

Comment: You can always dig into Blender source code itself to find out, but you can also read this paper: https://disney-animation.s3.amazonaws.com/library/s2012_pbs_disney_brdf_notes_v2.pdf as Principled BSDF is based on Disney work.